Grub rescueerror: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found
I'm using Ubuntu for past year, and now I'm trying to install Windows 10. While installing it displays
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
hrub rescue> _



This question is similar to: How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you're trying to remove Ubuntu and replace it with windows, you can ignore that issue as it will be gone if Windows is correctly installed. Boot your windows install media & install windows.   The error you show is a result of failure to correctly wipe details on your machine (eg. if you wiped a Ubuntu system on a dual boot environment without ensuring the other OS/windows controlled booting - this will be fixed with your windows recovery media).
